# Dask paralel job not better than without dask

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dask, joblib

I tried to dask paralel job like this:

```
from dask.distributed import Client
import joblib
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

client = Client(processes=False)             # create local cluster

with joblib.parallel_backend('dask'):
    tfidf.fit(corpus)
```

But the CPU usage is 100% of 400% same as without Dask. Am I missing something?

https://ml.dask.org/joblib.html

Answer (score 1):

In-process parallelism will wrk well when the calculations to be performed release the GIL, so that multiple threads can run simultaneously. This is true of many numerical libraries such as pandas and numpy, as used in the example you link to. However, text processing likely uses the python interpreter, so the GIL prevents more than one thread running at a time - hence the 100% CPU utilisation instead of something higher.

You may wish to try using processes instead, which is as simple as changing to

```
client = Client(processes=True)
```

(but there are many configuration options)

Comment: You are right that makes sense, I didn't notice that. Meanwhile I started to use Joblib paralel.

Comment: That's fine. Dask may have benefits where you broadcast data to workers or make more complex graphs; or, of course, want to expand to a work on a cluster.